# ngOninit runs only once - form is not updated

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, ngoninit

I have material sidenav container with material navigation list:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="cont">
            <mat-sidenav #drawer mode="side" opened role="navigation">
                <mat-nav-list>
                    <table>
                        <tr *ngFor = "let thing of values">
                            <td>
                                <button [class.selected]="thing === selectedThing" (click) = "onSelectedThing(thing)">{{thing.Date}}</button> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </mat-nav-list>
            </mat-sidenav>
            <mat-sidenav-content>

                    <app-thing [thing] = "selectedThing"></app-thing>

            </mat-sidenav-content>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
```

When I click on the button I send to app-thing component elements that should be viewed.

In  component I have:

```
<div>
        <app-add-costs [thingIDCost]="thing.thingId" 
        [Date1] = "thing.Date1" 
        [Date2] = "thing.Date2">
        </app-add-costs>
</div>
```

So I have another component where I send the parameters which are exposed in the form. 
app-add-costs component looks like:

```
export class AddCostsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() thingIDCost: number;
  @Input() Date1: string;
  @Input() Date2: string;

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private srv: HttpserviceService, private router: Router, private location: Location, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      Date1: [this.Date1, [Validators.required]],
      Date2: [this.Date2, [Validators.required]]
      }, {
        validator: this.validateDates
      }
      ),
  }
}
```

And In HMTL I just screen it in form:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="sendDates()">
<table align="right">
    <tr>
        <td>
                Date1
        </td >
        <td>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="datetime-local" formControlName="Date1">
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                Date2
        </td>
        <td>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="datetime-local" formControlName="Date2">
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And the problem is that the values Date1 and Date2 are not changing when I click through the navigation list. They keep holding the first values (from first element from the list).

I notices also that in Console I see that the OnInit is run only once.

How can I make the values seen when I move through the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace ngOnInit with ngOnChanges so it fires whenever the inputs change.

```
export class AddCostsComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input() thingIDCost: number;
  @Input() Date1: string;
  @Input() Date2: string;

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private srv: HttpserviceService, private router: Router, private location: Location, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      Date1: [this.Date1, [Validators.required]],
      Date2: [this.Date2, [Validators.required]]
      }, {
        validator: this.validateDates
      }
      ),
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value from component to another thought EventEmitter, so when you click on list item, you call a function that going to emmit an event, then you will receive it in the parent component then pass it to another child component.